# Java build error in Android apps packages

Tags: java, android, android-source, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build apps packages of LineageOS. I am getting the following error. This seems to be a JAVA error. I am using oracle jdk 8.

I am already using /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/ as my ANDROID_JAVA_HOME variable.

```
[  6% 196/3238] host Java: doclava (/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes)
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(rm -f /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar ) && (rm -rf /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes ) && (mkdir -p /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/ ) && (mkdir -p /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes ) && (for f in  /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/tagsouplib_intermediates/javalib.jar; do if [ ! -f \$f ]; then echo Missing file \$f; exit 1; fi; unzip -qo \$f -d /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes; done ) && (rm -rf /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/META-INF ) && (rm -f /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list ) && (touch /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list ) && (echo -n 'external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/AnnotationInstanceInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/AnnotationValueInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/AtLinksNavTree.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/AttrTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/AttributeInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ClassInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ClearPage.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/CodeTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Comment.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ContainerInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Converter.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/DocFile.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/DocInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Doclava.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Doclava2.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/DoclavaDiff.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Errors.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/FederatedSite.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/FederationTagger.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/FieldInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Hierarchy.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/InfoBuilder.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/InheritedTags.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/JarUtils.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/KeywordEntry.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/LinkReference.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/LiteralTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/MemberInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/MethodInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/NavTree.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/PackageInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/PageMetadata.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ParamTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ParameterInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ParsedTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Proofread.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Resolution.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Resolvable.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/SampleCode.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/SampleTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Scoped.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/SeeTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/SinceTagger.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Sorter.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/SourcePositionInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Stubs.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/TagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/TextTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/ThrowsTagInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/TodoFile.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/TypeInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/apicheck/AbstractMethodInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/apicheck/ApiCheck.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/apicheck/ApiFile.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/apicheck/ApiInfo.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/apicheck/ApiParseException.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/apicheck/XmlApiFile.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/parser/JavaLexer.java external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/parser/JavaParser.java ' >> /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list ) && (if [ -d \"/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/src\" ]; then find /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/src -name '*.java' -and -not -name '.*' >> /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list; fi ) && (tr ' ' '\\n' < /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list | build/tools/normalize_path.py | sort -u > /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list-uniq ) && (if [ -s /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list-uniq ] ; then javac -J-Xmx1024M -Xmaxerrs 9999999 -encoding UTF-8   -classpath /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/darwin-x86/framework/antlr-runtime.jar:/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/darwin-x86/framework/guavalib.jar:/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/darwin-x86/framework/jsilver.jar:/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/tagsouplib_intermediates/javalib.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar  -extdirs \"\" -d /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes -g  -source 1.8 -target 1.8 \\@/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list-uniq 2>/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/stderr && ( [ -s /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/stderr ] && echo \"\`cat /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/stderr\`\" 1>&2; rm -f /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/stderr ) || ( [ -s /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/stderr ] && echo \"\`cat /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/stderr\`\" 1>&2; rm -rf /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes; exit 41 ) fi ) && (rm -f /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list ) && (rm -f /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes/java-source-list-uniq ) && (jar -cf /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar -C /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes . ) && (rm -f  /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar.jar-arg-list ) && (touch  /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar.jar-arg-list ) && (echo -n '-C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/customizations/assets/customizations.css\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/customizations/assets/customizations.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/customizations/customizations.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/doclava-developer-core.css\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/doclava-developer-docs.css\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/doclava-developer-docs.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/doclava-developer-reference.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/bg_fade.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/bg_logo.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/body-gradient-tab.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/body-gradient.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/grad-rule-qv.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/hr_gray_main.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/hr_gray_side.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/left_off.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/left_on.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/preliminary.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/resizable-e.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/resizable-e2.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/resizable-eg.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/resizable-s.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/resizable-s2.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/resizable-sg.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/right_off.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/right_on.jpg\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/sidenav-rule.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/spacer.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/triangle-closed-small.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/triangle-closed.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/triangle-opened-small.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/images/triangle-opened.png\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/jquery-history.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/jquery-resizable.min.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/prettify.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/search_autocomplete.js\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/style.css\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/assets/triangle-none.gif\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/at_links_navtree.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/class.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/classes.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/components.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/components/api_filter.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/components/left_nav.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/components/masthead.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/components/search_box.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/data.hdf\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/designpage.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/diff.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/docpage.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/doctype.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/footer.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/head_tag.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/header.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/hierarchy.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/index.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/jd_lists.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/jd_lists_unified.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/keywords.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/lists.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/macros.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/navtree_data.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/nosidenavpage.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/package-list.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/package.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/packages.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/sample.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/sampleindex.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/timestamp.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/todo.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/trailer.cs\" -C \"external/doclava/res\" \"assets/templates/yaml_navtree.cs\" ' >>  /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar.jar-arg-list ) && (jar uf /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar @/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar.jar-arg-list ) && (rm -f /Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/doclava_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar.jar-arg-list )"
external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Converter.java:407: error: cannot find symbol
                    m.isAbstract(), m.isSynchronized(), m.isNative(), m.isDefault(), true,
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   method isDefault()
  location: variable m of type AnnotationTypeElementDoc
external/doclava/src/com/google/doclava/Converter.java:429: error: cannot find symbol
                    m.isAbstract(), m.isSynchronized(), m.isNative(), m.isDefault(), false,
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   method isDefault()
  location: variable m of type MethodDoc
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Help Please

Comment: Unlikely you will ever get any help building Lineage OS on Mac OS. Following instructions on http://www.lineageosrom.com/2017/01/how-to-build-lineageos-rom-for-any.html and https://source.android.com. You will need to use the appropriate Ubuntu version. If you use a Mac, you are on your own.

Comment: @satur9nine I got through this one. Now I am stuck with "kernel modules not enabled" when I try to build the entire os using brunch. Any clues?